# Getting: "Couldn't find SessionsHelper, expected it to be defined in helpers/sessions_helper.rb"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the following in my log file upon loading /login/.

`Started GET "/login" for 120.138.93.108 at 2016-01-02 03:06:24 +0000`

`ActionController::RoutingError (Couldn't find SessionsHelper, expected it to be defined in helpers/sessions_helper.rb):
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in`'
`app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:1:in`'

However, sessions_helper.rb does exist in the helpers folder. Furthermore, application_controller.rb and sessions_controller.rb are defined as Classes and the session_helper.rb as module.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem:

```
Couldn't find AgileTeamsHelper, expected it to be defined in helpers/agile_teams_helper.rb
```

It turns out I had this defined in my helper:

```
module AgileTeamHelper
  def td_color(text)
    if text == "Green"
      "green-background"
    elsif text == "Yellow"
      "yellow-background"
    elsif text == "Red"
      "red-background"
    end
  end
end
```

Instead of:

```
module AgileTeamsHelper # <-- (Notice the extra s after teams)
  def td_color(text)
    if text == "Green"
      "green-background"
    elsif text == "Yellow"
      "yellow-background"
    elsif text == "Red"
      "red-background"
    end
  end
end
```

In this case I was missing the 's' in 'AgileTeamsHelper'. I believe that rails looks for a module with the same as the helper, but camel cased. IE. `'agile_teams_helper'.camelize` -> `"AgileTeamsHelper"`

Answer (score 2):

I simply followed the age-old advice:

> when in doubt, restart your server

and that was enough for me. I was absolutely sure the code was alright.

Answer (score 2):

## TL; DR

Sometimes it's not the problem of helpers.  Delete all the helpers and see what happens next.

## Body

It seems if the loading (reading the class file, eval the content to define the class/module defined inside) of the controller itself fails with whatever reason, it shows this error.

In my case, there was a class from a gem which was intended to be used by `include`ing to the controller, which overrides `included` method, and did some initialization process.  The problem was, this `include` method raised an exception, which prevented the Controller to get loaded, and I don't know why but resulted in a situation just like as described in this question.

I found out the root cause by deleting all the helpers and checking what happens next.  If error changes and you find it to be happening on the loading of the Controller, then now you can fix it.

```rb
# Example class of what have caused the Helper not found in my case
class FooController
  include SomeGemWhichRaiseExceptionOnInclude
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by re-creating helpers/sessions_helper.rb (using touch) and filling it with the exact same contents. Weird, but it worked.

Comment: Just touching all the helper files worked. Really weird, stopping spring and clearing caches didn't.

Comment: I had such a case, I realized that I had a piece of code that I had an if control structure which was not closed. So I thinking the touching of helper files was simply removing all code that was causing an error, in your case

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out this may not be an issue with helpers and the error from helpers may be masking the real issue. At least this was my experience upgrading a Rails 4 application to Rails 5.

@TKChattoraj suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662462/actioncontrollerroutingerror-couldnt-find-expected-it-to-be-defined-in), that rather than deleting all helpers in Rails 5+ you can add `config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false` to config/environments/development.rb which will eliminate any false positives that are coming from your helpers.  At least that is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in including non-existing helper (typo)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this myself right after creating a new helper, and the errors I got were that Rails couldn't find a different helper.

This ended up being due to the fact that I had improperly named the module (was `ReCaptchaHelper`, needed to be `RecaptchaHelper`) defined within the new helper file (`recaptcha_helper.rb`).

Check if any new code you added to a helper has a syntax error, and if you added a new helper, make sure that the module's name is properly formatted in accordance with the filename (ex: `the_new_helper.rb` should have a module called `TheNewHelper`)