# Rails 4.2: After manual changing of model name Rails server complains about helpers for the old model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm working on Rails4.2/mongoid application.

I needed to change the name for one model and did it manually. I'm confident that there is no mention  of the old model name in any of the files, checked over and over again manually and then with grep.
Also changed the collection name in MongoDB

Attempt to open any url on the application results in

`Couldn't find ExamplesHelper, expected it to be defined in helpers/examples_helper.rb`

Application trace point's to

`app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'`
`app/controllers/home_controller.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'`

There is no mention of any models/controllers/helpers in the above controllers. These are the only two inheriting from `ActionController::Base`

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562224/getting-couldnt-find-sessionshelper-expected-it-to-be-defined-in-helpers-ses), but can't say I like the solution.

Can anybody at least point me in the right direction? Really stumped with this one.

Comment: Did you clear spring, kill ruby processes, etc (Sorry for the "Did you turn it off and back on again" comment)

Comment: have you renamed the file ? example.rb should be renamed too

Comment: Did you try to restart the rails server?

Comment: Ok, I found it. Grep worked OK but I should have used `find . -name "example*"` too to make sure I renamed all the files. Now the funny bit: The one I missed was app/helpers/examples_helper.rb, yes, the one rails said it can't find ... go figure. It started working once I renamed this helper in line with the new model name. Thanks @niceman for reminding me to check the file names again.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a helper:

```
# app/helpers/examples_helper.rb

module ExamplesHelper
end
```

Comment: The Example model doesn't exist anymore, it was renamed to something else but rails keeps asking for it.

Comment: then find where word `example` meets in your project and remove this lines

Comment: @itsnikolay he said he used `grep` to verify the word doesn't exist :)

Comment: @BartC try to run `spring stop` and rerun you server