# ActionController::RoutingError (Couldn't find..., expected it to be defined in...)

Tags: actioncontroller, ruby-on-rails-5.1

So...first time asking a question to StackOverflow...

I converted an existing Rails 4.2.5 app (using Ruby 2.2.4) to a Rails 5.1.3 app (using Ruby 2.4.1), following the Rails Guides and the RailsApps Project.

Firing up the development server produces:

```
Taruns-iMac:Play_Ball tarunchattoraj$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Private Caller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

which is what I would expect.

Navigating to localhost:3000, however, produces an the ActionController error:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-13 11:05:38 -0400
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  
ActionController::RoutingError (Couldn't find Api::KeepScoresHelper, expected it to be defined in helpers/api/keep_scores_helper.rb):
  
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

I expected to see my app running on the page normally.

## My Question:

### What is causing this ActionController::RoutingError (Couldn't find...) and how to correct it?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562224/getting-couldnt-find-sessionshelper-expected-it-to-be-defined-in-helpers-ses) seems to be on point.  I tried the solution of "touching" all the helper files but to no avail.

When I converted from Rails 4.2.5 to 5.1.3, I ran  `$ rails app:update` and I overwrote most files--those in which I didn't have code specific to my app, but I chose not to overwrite config/routes.rb.

config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :alerts
  get 'games/decide_game_view' => 'games#decide_game_view', as: :decide_game_view
  resources :games
  resources :game_hitting_stats
  resources :game_pitching_stats
  resources :locations
  resources :players
  get 'welcome/index'

  get 'welcome/about'



  resources :users do
    resources :players
  end

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :teams do
    resources :notes
  end

  # namespace :api, defaults: {format: :http} do
  namespace :api do
    match '/texts', to: 'texts#preflight', via: [:options]
    resources :texts, only: [:create]

    match '/keepscore/teams', to: 'keep_scores#preflight', via: [:options]
    get 'keepscore/teams' => 'keep_scores#get_teams', as: :get_teams

    match '/keepscore/roster', to: 'keep_scores#preflight', via: [:options]
    get 'keepscore/roster' => 'keep_scores#get_roster', as: :get_roster

    match '/keepscore/post_game_stats', to: 'keep_scores#preflight', via: [:options]
    post 'keepscore/post_game_stats' => 'keep_scores#post_game_stats', as: :post_game_stats

  end
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

ActionController seems to be telling me that it can't find the KeepScoresHelper Module and that its looking in helpers/api/keep_scores_helper.rb.  But that file exists See [Pic of App Controller and Helper Tree Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlqFU.png).

The contents of helpers/api/keep_scores_helper.rb:

```
module API::KeepScoresHelper
end
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby "2.4.1"
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.1.3'
gem 'puma'

gem 'pundit'
gem 'bcrypt'

gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'pry'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :test do
  gem 'pundit-matchers', '~>1.0.1'
end

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'listen'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 3.5.1'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views

  gem 'sqlite3'


end
```

Of course any help is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 6):

In config/environments/development.rb, set:

`config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false`

This returns Helpers to pre-Rails 5 behavior.  Per [RoR API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html), for Rails 5.1.3, "By default, each controller will include all helpers."  Pre Rails 5, the controller would include a helper matched to its name.  Making the setting as specified above returns to the Pre-Rails 5 behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Adding in hopes of helping others that stumble across this.

## Initial Trouble Shooting

I had this same issue when upgrading the same versions you mention in your question. I did upgrade from 4.2 to 5.0 first though then upgrade to 5.1.3 from there.

The first upgrade worked fine but I started receiving the same error message (e.g. `uninitialized constant ActionController::RedirectBackError ...` about not being able to find the helpers but this only happened when I jumped to rails 5.1.

I tried a lot of other fixes as outlined in this [github issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18660) as it seemed to be the same error but nothing worked and my paths all seemed to be correct (no discrepancies in path or casing).

## My Fix

I ended up deleting all helpers and received a new error which lead me to finding the code in my app that was causing the problem.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
# Catch exceptions if :back is not set throughout the app. This is a fallback redirect if request.referer is not set.

rescue_from ActionController::RedirectBackError do |exception|
  redirect_to key_activities_ministries_activities_path, alert: exception.message
end
```

That code was causing a Routing Error: `uninitialized constant ActionController::RedirectBackError`. But this error only appeared when I removed all of my helpers.  **I removed this code, put my helpers back, and restarted my server and everything worked as expected.**